# Automatically set mongoose schema properties on save or update

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, restify

I have a question.. How can I configure my mongoose schema in such a way that it sets certain fields on save and/or update?

Here is what I'm trying to do.
I have a User schema, and when the new document is created I want the `createdOn` field be set with current date.
And when the existing document is updated, I want the `updatedOn` field be set with current date

```
// user.model.ts
import { Document, Model, model, Schema } from 'mongoose';
import PasswordUtil from '../../../util/PasswordUtil';

export interface IUser extends Document {
    username: string;
    createdOn: Date;
    updatedOn: Date;
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    email: string;
    password: string;
}

const encryptPassword = (password: string) => PasswordUtil.encrypt(password);

export const UserSchema = new Schema<IUser>({
    username: {
        required: true,
        type: String,
        unique: true
    },
    createdOn: {
        required: true,
        type: Date,
        set: Date.now
    },
    updatedOn: {
        required: true,
        type: Date
    },
    firstName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    lastName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        set: encryptPassword
    }
});

export const UserModel: Model<IUser> = model('User', UserSchema);
```

I have `set: Date.now` for `createdOn` property. I don't want the client to send this value. But since there is no `createdOn` in the model, the validation fails as I have also configured `createdOn` with `required: true`. Same is the case with `updatedOn`.
This is how I am doing it right now

```
// user.controller.ts
public createUser(request: Request, response: Response) {
    const user: IUser = request.body as IUser;

    const userSchema = new UserModel(user);
    userSchema.set('updatedOn', Date.now());
    userSchema.set('createdOn', Date.now());
    userSchema.save()
        .then((model: IUser) => ResponseHelper.responseOK(response, model))
        .catch((err: MongoError) => ResponseHelper.responseInternalServerError(response, { message: err.message }));
}
```

how can I make it so that all this logic to set the `createdOn` and `updatedOn` fields resides within the model itself?
also, the `createdOn` should be set when new model is created and
`updatedOn` should be set when the existing model is updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use 'default' in your Schema (https://mongoosejs.com/docs/defaults.html). This will set the current date on creation.

```
 createdOn: {
  required: true,
  type: Date,
  set: Date.now,
  default: Date.now
},
updatedOn: {
  required: true,
  type: Date,
  default: Date.now
}
```

As for to update the timestamp on a .update - If you are running mongoose >4.0, you can use timestamps

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#timestamps

Answer (score 4):

You can add [`timestamps`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#timestamps) to your schema and it will automatically create `createdAt` and `updatedAt` fields, `updatedAt` will get updated every time you update the document

```
export const UserSchema = new Schema<IUser>({/* schema */}, { timestamps: true })
```

You can also rename the fields like this

```
{ timestamps: { createdAt: 'createdOn', updatedAt: 'updatedOn' }}
```